# PostgreSQL - How to do a Loop on a column

Tags: postgresql

I am struggling to do a loop on a Postgres, but functions on postgres are not my piece of cake.

I have the following table on postgres:

```
|  portfolio_1   | total_risk |
|----------------|------------|
| Top 10 Bets    |            |
| AAPL34         |    2,06699 |
| DISB34         |   1,712684 |
| PETR4          |   0,753324 |
| PETR3          |   0,087767 |
| VALE3          |   0,086346 |
| LREN3          |   0,055108 |
| AMZO34         |        0,0 |
| Bottom 10 Bets |            |
| AAPL34         |        0,0 |
```

What I'm trying to do is get the values after the "Top 10 Bets" and before the "Botton 10 Bets".

My goal is the following result:

```
| portfolio_1 | total_risk |
|-------------|------------|
| AAPL34      |    2,06699 |
| DISB34      |   1,712684 |
| PETR4       |   0,753324 |
| PETR3       |   0,087767 |
| VALE3       |   0,086346 |
| LREN3       |   0,055108 |
| AMZO34      |        0,0 |
```

So, my goal is to take off the "Top 10 Bets", the "Botton 10 Bets" and the AAPL34 after the "Botton 10 Bets", which was repeated. 
The quantity of rows is variable (I'm importing it from an Excel file), so I need a loop to do this, right?

Comment: "before" and "after" only have a meaning in a relational database if you can apply an `ORDER BY` - so which column can be used to sort the rows of that table so that "before" and "after" get a meaning? Or do you simply want all rows where total_risk is not null?

Comment: please update your question with expected result, and a sample data set that will generate the expected result.

Comment: Hey @a_horse_with_no_name, I updated my question. And a plus: my table have a "Insert Data" column (wich is datetime). So I have a order (or a rank).

Comment: hey @HaleemurAli, I updated my question!

Comment: Can you include the query you use to get the results shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "before" or "after" unless rows explicitly provide that information.

Let me assume that you have such a column, which I will call `id` for convenience.

Then you can do this in several ways.  Here is one:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id > (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.portfolio_1 = 'Top 10 Bets') and
      t.id < (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.portfolio_1 = 'Bottom 10 Bets');
```

Comment: You're correct, Gordon. I forgot to mention that on my original question. Your answers, despite of that, helped me A LOT. Thank you!